# yum Error:rpmdb open failed

Tags: centos, yum

I'm trying to run `yum update` and I'm running this error:

```
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from dbenv->open: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 - (-30974)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

I checked page [like this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/error-rpmdb-open-failed-4175469229/) one but running `yum clean all` runs the same error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This may happen also when running `yum install` as well. Thanks for this question

Answer (score 141, accepted):

This is how I fixed my problem.

You may fix this by cleaning out rpm database. But first, in order to minimize the risk, make sure you create a backup of files in `/var/lib/rpm/` using `cp` command:

```
mkdir /root/backups.rpm.mm_dd_yyyy/
cp -avr /var/lib/rpm/ /root/backups.rpm.mm_dd_yyyy/
```

The try this to fix this problem:

```
# rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
# db_verify /var/lib/rpm/Packages
# rpm --rebuilddb
# yum clean all
```

And finally verify that error has gone with the following yum command

```
# yum update
```

Comment: This solution seems to work with dnf instead of yum as well.

Comment: I get "unfinished transactions remaining.." after doing all this, and the broken packages that created the problem continues to block any future installations.  For that matter, why would the end-user need to see/do any of this?  If the yum-db has an issue, it should clean/fix itself automatically - with at most a y/n prompt which an os-tinkerer might want to opt out of.  Found the fix for my case - do the above, then do "yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only"

Comment: Why not just `cd /var/lib/rpm; db_recover` ? In most cases that's much less of a nuclear option.

Comment: I find `sudo rpm --rebuilddb` alone solves my case. Nevertheless always backup `/var/lib/rpm` for safe.

Comment: For those who still see the killed message on yum install, just restart your server. Yes, it sucks to restart to get something basic like this working, but that was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: worked for me as well

Answer (score 3):

All I had to do was to delete the two file with the ".lock" extension, and the three files that started with "__db".

```
# rm /var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock
# rm /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock
# rm /var/lib/rpm/__db*
```

After that, `yum update` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex, your answer worked for me apart from one slight change I had to make.

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
```

returned errors

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/rpm/__db.001': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/rpm/__db.002': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/rpm/__db.004': Is a directory
```

so I had to recurse with

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db*
```

Comment: Those should not be directories.  If you see that, then you may want to run `fsck` on your partition to ensure you don't have file corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above one it did'nt work

below works fine

```
# cd /var/lib
# tar -zcvf /var/preserve/rpmdb-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).tar.gz rpm
```

Note: This tar backup can be used if the attempt to recover the RPM database has issues.

Verify integrity of the Packages file:

```
# cd /var/lib/rpm
# rm -f __db*      # to avoid stale locks
# /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_verify Packages

# mv Packages Packages.orig
# /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_dump Packages.orig | /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_load Packages


# rpm -vv --rebuilddb
```

Once again verify RPM database:

```
# cd /var/lib/rpm
# /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_verify Packages
```

Comment: On running `sudo /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_dump Packages.orig | /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_load Packages` I get the following error:
`rpmdb_load: DB->open: Packages: Permission denied`

Comment: It would be better if you raise a Question for this. Also mentioen which user are you trying to connect?