# 'yum' command fails with 'TypeError: rpmdb open failed' in Red Hat 5.2

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

I'm unable to run **yum** command on my Linux machine.
I'm getting the following errors:

```
dispsim:~$ yum
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 - Invalid argument (22)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 85, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 163, in getOptionsConfig
    disabled_plugins=self.optparser._splitArg(opts.disableplugins))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 164, in _getConf
ig
    self._conf = config.readMainConfig(startupconf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 685, in readMainCo
nfig
    yumvars['releasever'] = _getsysver(startupconf.installroot, startupconf.dist
roverpkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 752, in _getsysver
    idx = ts.dbMatch('provides', distroverpkg)
TypeError: rpmdb open failed
```

Redhat-release is **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga)**

```
dispsim-1:~$ uname -a
Linux dispsim 2.6.18-92.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 29 13:16:12 EDT 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I also tried the following steps:

```
1. su
2. rm /var/lib/rpm/__db.00*
3. rpm --rebuilddb
```

But this didn't resolve the issue. Any suggestions on this please?

Comment: @ray: `yum clean all` is also not working. Throwing same errors.

Comment: What was the last successful yum/rpm operation you ran on this system before this error showed up?

Comment: @ray: Sorry, I really don't remember now. It is an old issue on my test bench.

Comment: Last 10 package installs, with date and time  :  `$ rpm -qa --last | head -10`

Comment: What does `rpm -V rpm` run as root say?

Comment: Does this help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198703/yum-errorrpmdb-open-failed

Comment: @Knud Larsen: Last 10 installed packages were: `1. sshpass-1.05-1.el5                            Mon 12 Jan 2015 04:35:27 AM BRST`
`2. kobo-rpmlib-0.3.6-1.el5                       Thu 26 Jul 2012 06:10:03 AM BRT`
`3. kobo-0.3.6-1.el5                              Thu 26 Jul 2012 06:09:59 AM BRT`
`4. python-ssl-1.15-3.el5                         Thu 26 Jul 2012 06:09:58 AM BRT`
`5. koji-1.7.0-2.el5                              Thu 26 Jul 2012 06:09:56 AM BRT`

Comment: `6. epel-release-5-4                              Tue 15 Mar 2011 06:43:29 PM BRT` `7. rpm-5.0-0.2.0.el5.rf                          Tue 22 Jun 2010 10:31:40 PM BRT` `8. rpm-libs-5.0-0.2.0.el5.rf                     Tue 22 Jun 2010 10:28:46 PM BRT` `9. python-hashlib-20081119-4.el5                 Tue 22 Jun 2010 08:52:51 PM BRT` `10. python-krbV-1.0.90-1.el5                      Tue 22 Jun 2010 08:52:50 PM BRT`