# CentOS dist update fail

Tags: centos, yum

When updating CentOS yum has crashed and left me with `Error: rpmdb open failed`. I tired to fix it with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198703/yum-errorrpmdb-open-failed#198704) and it left me with working yum and some unfinished transactions.

I then evoke `yum-complete-transaction` and tried `yum history undo last` but latter failed, so I evoke `yum check` (output below). Later on I tried to remove all duplicated packages with `yum remove $(cat list)`, where 'list' is file with space-separated list of packages from `yum check`. As a result I get whole lot of dependencies to remove including protected packages (systemd and yum).

I don't know where should I go from this point. Should I provide some additional command outputs?

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that system didn't boot with new kernel (quite obviously).

```
# yum list "kernel" 
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                                               3.10.0-327.18.2.el7                                                                               @updates 
kernel.x86_64                                                                               3.10.0-327.22.2.el7                                                                               @updates 
kernel.x86_64                                                                               3.10.0-327.36.2.el7                                                                               @updates 
kernel.x86_64                                                                               3.10.0-327.36.3.el7                                                                               @updates 
kernel.x86_64                                                                               3.10.0-514.2.2.el7                                                                                installed
```

Yum check log:
# yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

```
audit-libs-2.6.5-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-libs-2.4.1-5.el7.x86_64
binutils-2.25.1-22.base.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with binutils-2.23.52.0.1-55.el7.x86_64
centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64
coreutils-8.22-18.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with coreutils-8.22-15.el7_2.1.x86_64
cronie-1.4.11-14.el7_2.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with cronie-1.4.11-14.el7.x86_64
1:dbus-libs-1.6.12-017.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:dbus-libs-1.6.12-14.el7_2.x86_64
1:dmidecode-3.0-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:dmidecode-2.12-9.el7.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-0.166-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with elfutils-libelf-0.163-3.el7.x86_64
2:ethtool-4.5-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2:ethtool-3.15-2.el7.x86_64
expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64 is a duplicate with expat-2.1.0-8.el7.x86_64
filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
glibc-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64
glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with kernel-    tools-libs-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
libX11-common-1.6.3-3.el7.noarch is a duplicate with libX11-common-1.6.3-2.el7.noarch
libcom_err-1.42.9-9.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64
libffi-3.0.13-18.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libffi-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64
libgcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64
libgcrypt-1.5.3-13.el7_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgcrypt-1.5.3-12.el7_1.1.x86_64
libgomp-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgomp-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64
libndp-1.2-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libndp-1.2-6.el7_2.x86_64
libnl3-3.2.28-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libnl3-3.2.21-10.el7.x86_64
libselinux-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64
libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libsepol-2.1.9-3.el7.x86_64
libtalloc-2.1.6-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libtalloc-2.1.5-1.el7_2.x86_64
libtasn1-3.8-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libtasn1-3.8-2.el7.x86_64
libuuid-2.23.2-33.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libuuid-2.23.2-26.el7_2.3.x86_64
lm_sensors-libs-3.4.0-4.20160601gitf9185e5.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with lm_sensors-libs-3.3.4-11.el7.x86_64
lsscsi-0.27-4.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with lsscsi-0.27-3.el7.x86_64
lua-5.1.4-15.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with lua-5.1.4-14.el7.x86_64
nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.4.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.2.el7_2.x86_64
nss-util-3.21.3-1.1.el7_3.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-util-3.21.0-2.2.el7_2.x86_64
pciutils-libs-3.5.1-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with pciutils-libs-3.2.1-4.el7.x86_64
setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch is a duplicate with setup-2.8.71-6.el7.noarch
xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with xz-libs-5.1.2-12alpha.el7.x86_64
Error: check all
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I don't know why I tried to remove those broken packages instead of reinstalling them, hence the kinda hackish way to reinstall all broken packages:

`yum reinstall $(yum check | awk 'NR!=1{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ')`